# Python: How to add specific columns of .mean to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I add the means of b and c to my dataframe? I tried a merge but it didn't seem to work. So I want two extra columns b_mean and c_mean added to my dataframe with the results of `df.groupBy('date').mean()`

DataFrame

```
  a  b  c  date
0  2  3  5     1
1  5  9  1     1
2  3  7  1     1
```

I have the following code

```
import pandas as pd

a = [{'date': 1,'a':2, 'b':3, 'c':5}, {'date':1, 'a':5, 'b':9, 'c':1}, {'date':1, 'a':3, 'b':7, 'c':1}]

df = pd.DataFrame(a)

x =  df.groupby('date').mean()
```

Edit:

Desired output would be the following
`df.groupby('date').mean()` returns:

```
             a         b         c
date                              
1     3.333333  6.333333  2.333333
```

My desired result would be the following data frame

```
   a  b  c  date  a_mean   b_mean
0  2  3  5     1  3.3333   6.3333
1  5  9  1     1  3.3333   6.3333 
2  3  7  1     1  3.3333   6.3333
```

Comment: You probably want groupby.transform but please add the desired output so that it's clearer.

Answer (score 8):

As @ayhan mentioned, you can use [pd.groupby.transform()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) for this. Transform is like apply, but it uses the same index as the original dataframe instead of the unique values in the column(s) grouped on.

```
df['a_mean'] = df.groupby('date')['a'].transform('mean')
df['b_mean'] = df.groupby('date')['b'].transform('mean')

>>> df
   a  b  c  date    b_mean    a_mean
0  2  3  5     1  6.333333  3.333333
1  5  9  1     1  6.333333  3.333333
2  3  7  1     1  6.333333  3.333333
```

Comment: This is a great solution as well.

Answer (score 6):

***solution***
Use `join` with a `rsuffix` parameter.

```
df.join(df.groupby('date').mean(), on='date', rsuffix='_mean')

   a  b  c  date    a_mean    b_mean    c_mean
0  2  3  5     1  3.333333  6.333333  2.333333
1  5  9  1     1  3.333333  6.333333  2.333333
2  3  7  1     1  3.333333  6.333333  2.333333
```

---

We can limit it to just `['a', 'b']`

```
df.join(df.groupby('date')[['a', 'b']].mean(), on='date', rsuffix='_mean')

   a  b  c  date    a_mean    b_mean
0  2  3  5     1  3.333333  6.333333
1  5  9  1     1  3.333333  6.333333
2  3  7  1     1  3.333333  6.333333
```

***extra credit***
Not really answering your question... but I thought it was neat!

```
d1 = df.set_index('date', append=True).swaplevel(0, 1)
g = df.groupby('date').describe()
d1.append(g).sort_index()

                   a         b         c
date                                    
1    0      2.000000  3.000000  5.000000
     1      5.000000  9.000000  1.000000
     2      3.000000  7.000000  1.000000
     25%    2.500000  5.000000  1.000000
     50%    3.000000  7.000000  1.000000
     75%    4.000000  8.000000  3.000000
     count  3.000000  3.000000  3.000000
     max    5.000000  9.000000  5.000000
     mean   3.333333  6.333333  2.333333
     min    2.000000  3.000000  1.000000
     std    1.527525  3.055050  2.309401
```

Answer (score 3):

I assuming that you need mean value of a column added as a new column value in the dataframe. Please correct me otherwise.

You can achieve by taking the mean of column directly and create a new column by assigning like

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: a = [{'date': 1,'a':2, 'b':3, 'c':5}, {'date':1, 'a':5, 'b':9, 'c':1}, {'date':1, 'a':3, 'b':7, 'c':1}]

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame(a)

In [4]: for col in ['b','c']:
    ...:      df[col+"_mean"] = df.groupby('date')[col].transform('mean')

In [5]: df
Out[5]:
   a  b  c  date    b_mean    c_mean
0  2  3  5     1  6.333333  2.333333
1  5  9  1     1  6.333333  2.333333
2  3  7  1     1  6.333333  2.333333
```

Comment: The iteration is nice, but OP needs a solution that accommodates grouping.